# Community Wiki bounties should be split

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty, community-wiki

I believe that bounties that are awarded to community wiki questions should be split according to the work done by each user(See the percentages under any community wiki answer to get this data) instead of giving all to the original user. Or, the person giving the bounty can choose how to distribute the bounty manually. Feel free to add other opinions to the mix.

Comment: This is an interesting idea.

Comment: How would you split this? A split based on character count wouldn't necessarily be fair as _its quality that counts, not quantity_ as my teachers used to say

Comment: @jackweirdy I do agree with the quote, so this could be hard to implement: possibly weighted based on how the upvote rate increases after each edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## I agree: automatically split

This should be done by automatically splitting according to the amount of work done by each user.

Answer (score -2):

## I agree: manually split

This should be done by allowing the person awarding the bounty to manually choose how much goes to each user.

Answer (score -3):

## I disagree

This should not be implemented and the behavior left as is: the person creating the answer gets all.

Comment: Looks as if this may be the solution through inaction...